# Set height of a div to match the remaining height without position and calc

Tags: html, css

My target browser if firefox 10. I have two divisions surrounded by another. The first one represents  a header and second one represents the body. The surrounding div represents a container. `header` div's height is 50px and I want `body` div to occupy the remaining height. I wrote this sample code and I see the `body` div is taking the container's height and I get a scrollbar.

```
body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.container-style {
    height: 100%;
}
.header-style {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
}
.body-style {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```
<div id="container" class="container-style">
    <div id="header" class="header-style">
    </div>
    <div id="body" class="body-style">
    </div>
</div>
```

I then used calc css5 method and solved it. Below is the code

```
.body-style {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

But this wont work on browsers which do not support css5. Then I used css position property to do achieve it.

```
.body-style {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

I don't know whether it works for other browsers. But at least it will work on firefox 10.

I want to know is there any solution which does not involve using css position property and an easy solution.

Comment: Use margin-top instead of padding-top

Comment: That looks easy as it is. If it works what's the problem? Do you want the body to expand dynamically with the content or to stay in place and scroll?

Comment: @leigero yeah it works fine. But I just wanted to know is there any other solution without using `position: absolute`

Comment: @Igle Margin-top will not do. Because border-box will not consider margin while calculating the height. Then I will get a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Do you want the body to never expand when the content of the body exceeds the length?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this question. It sounds like you're asking "how do I accomplish X without doing it the way you're supposed to. I did it the way it should be done, and the way it works, but I want to do it another way."

Comment: @leigero I asked this question out of curiosity to learn whether it can be improved in any way. I somewhere read we should be careful while using css position attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add negative `margin-top` to counter-act your `padding-top`. Your `padding-top` is currently equal to 50px, but your header element has a 1px border, so your `padding-top` therefore should be equal to 52px:

```css
.body-style {
    ...
    padding-top: 52px;
}
```

Your `margin-top` will need to be equal to -52px:

```css
.body-style {
    ...
    padding-top: 52px;
    margin-top: -52px;
}
```

Your `.body-style` selector will now look like this:

```css
.body-style {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 52px;
    margin-top: -52px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/vP3ph/).